# How to turn off two factor authorization in Joomla 3 without access to admin panel

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

How to turn off two factor authorization in Joomla 3 without access to admin panel? I have access to ftp, mysql, but can't login to admin, key in Android application was lost :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have access to the database via PhpMyAdmin or something similar, then go to the `#__extensions` table and under the `name` column, search for `plg_twofactorauth_totp`. Within this row, set the `enabled` status to `0`

Hope this helps

Comment: No effect, after i disabled plg_twofactorauth_totp , joomla still asks me secret key.

Comment: Ok, i had to disable plg_twofactorauth_yubikey too